# Why doesn't this construction make the rational numbers a $G_\delta$ set?

Tags: general-topology, descriptive-set-theory, borel-sets

A $G_\delta$ set is a countable intersection of open sets.  The set of rational numbers is not a $G_\delta$ set.

But I'm wondering why the following construction doesn't make it a $G_\delta$ set.  Let $(q_n)$ be a sequence enumerating the rational numbers.  For any natural number $m$, let $U_m = \cup_n (q_n-\frac{1}{2^{m+n}},q_n+\frac{1}{2^{m+n}})$, and let $U = \cap_m U_m$.  Then it seems to me that $U_m$ is an open set for all $m$, and $U$ is the set of rational numbers.  So the set of rational numbers is a $G_\delta$ set.

Where is the flaw in my reasoning?

Comment: The flaw in your reasoning is your argument for $U$ being the set of rational numbers. In fact, you gave no argument. ("It seems to me" is not an argument.) How do you prove that every element of $U$ is a rational number?

Comment: @bof Here’s my reasoning: if $x$ is an irrational number, then for any natural number $n$ there exists a natural number $m$ such that $x$ is not in the $n^{th}$ interval of $U_m$.  In any case, assuming I’m wrong (which I of course must be), can you tell me an irrational number that is in $U$?

Comment: There will always be irrational numbers in $U$ but I can't identify one without knowing what enumeration of the rationals you are using. In my answer below I do this for one particular enumeration, chosen to make my task easy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many ways to enumerate the rational numbers. Since you did not specify an enumeration, let me pick one for you.

For each positive integer $m$, choose a rational number $q_{2m}$ so that $|q_{2m}-\sqrt2|\lt\frac1{2^{3m}}$. In this way we get a sequence $q_2,q_4,q_6,\dots$ of rational numbers converging to $\sqrt2$. Enumerate the rest of the rational numbers any way you like in a sequence $q_1,q_3,q_5,\dots$. Conbining these, we get an enumeration $q_1,q_2,q_3,\dots$ of the set of all rational numbers.

Note that, for each positive integer $m$, we now have
$$\sqrt2\in\left(q_{2m}-\frac1{2^{m+2m}},\ q_{2m}+\frac1{2^{m+2m}}\right)\subseteq\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty\left(q_n-\frac1{2^{m+n}},\ q_n+\frac1{2^{m+n}}\right)=U_m,$$
so $\sqrt2\in\bigcap_{m=1}^\infty U_m$, although $\sqrt2$ is not a rational number.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  By the way, is the intersection of all G delta sets containing the set of rational numbers simply the set of rational numbers, or is there a smallest G delta set containing the rational numbers?

Comment: For any set $A\subseteq\mathbb R$ we have $$A=\bigcap_{x\in\mathbb R\setminus A}(\mathbb R\setminus\{x\}),$$ so any set is the intersection of open sets containing it.

Comment: OK that makes sense.  So then is there any notion of what the smallest number of elements you need to add to the set of rational numbers to get a $G_{\delta}$ set?  Is $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt 2]$ a $G_{\delta}$ set?

Comment: Have you seen a proof of the fact that $\mathbb Q$ is not a $G_\delta$ set? The proof (which uses the Baire category theorem) does not use any arithmetic/algebraic properties of rational numbers, it applies to any countable dense subset of $\mathbb R.$ Since $\mathbb Q[\sqrt2]$ is a countable dense set, it is not a $G_\delta$ set.

Comment: Oh ok, thanks for clarifying.